# Записать в массив сначала все положительные числа и нули, а затем все отрицательные

Tags: c, массивы

Дан массив действительных чисел, содержащий 25 элементов, записать в этот же массив сначала все положительные числа и нули, а затем все отрицательные, сохраняя порядок их следования.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define N 10
int main()
{
    int i,buf,k,j;
    int array[N]={10,2,-4,-5,1,0,0,-7,1,2};

    for(i=0;i<N;++i,k=0)//главный цыкл
    {
       if(array[i]>=0) printf("%d",array[i]); //проверка,если положительное или ноль-печать.
       else
       {
           for(k=0;array[k]<0 || i!=N-1;++k) //в этом цыкле поиск чисел больше нуля
           { 
                 array[k]=array[i+k];

                      if(k==N-1 && array[k]<0) //проверка не закончился ли цыкл,если да-печать всех отрицательных.
                      {
                                  for(;i<N;++i)
                                  printf("%d  ",array[i]);
                                  i=N; //это условие конца главного цыкла.
                      }

           }     
                if(array[k]>=0) /*проверка числа на положительность,затем менять местами
                                       в масиве до тех пор,пока он не станет на первый елемент,или предедущие
                                       тоже положительное или ноль*/
                {
                   for(;array[k-1]<0 || array[k]!=array[0];--k)
                   {
                        buf=array[k-1];array[k-1]=array[k];array[k]=buf;
                   } 
                }
         if(i!=N) printf(" %d  ",array[k]); //печать елемент масива         
       }

    }

getch();
return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Код вы привели, а какая у вас проблема?

Comment: Проблема решить задачу.:)

Comment: проблема в том,что печатает только элементы которые первые положительные или ноль,дальше работать не хочет)

Comment: //в этом цыкле поиск чисел больше нуля

где там конкретно поиск числел больше нуля в том цикле?

>array[k]=array[i+k];

Что это за сдвиг влево элементов? Пока такие вопросы...

Comment: поиск чисел,пока каждый следующий элемент меньше нуля,искать положительный число или ноль,пока его не найдём!а потом начинаем работать с этим элементом..то есть менять его местами с прошедшим элементом)

Comment: Пока каждый следующий элемент меньше нуля? Оно идет вконец массива ваще так как i!=N-1 , далеко далеко, еще и смещая элементы влево. Пофикси.

Comment: @bonapart, печать массива выделите в отдельную функцию и вызовете ее в самом конце программы. А можно и в начале вызвать, что бы показать исходный массив.

--

Код сразу упростится, станет очевидней. В результате Вы легко сможете его еще немного оптимизировать.

Comment: мне и нужно что бы он туда ишол)

Comment: совет за функцию спасибо-оптимизирую)

Comment: Давай бонапарт действуй ) все будет ок